# Converting two complex dictionary list to a dictionary

Tags: python, django

suppose I have two dictionary list below:

```
  all=[]
  lis1={
    'code':'matata',
    'commandes':[
        {
            'date':'12-10-22',
            'content':[
                {
                    'article':'Article1',
                    'designation':'Designe1',
                    'quantity':5
                }
            ]
         }
      ]
    }
 
 lis2={
     'code':'fropm',
     'commandes':[
       {
        'date':'04-08-21',
        'content':[
            {
                'article':'Article2',
                'designation':'Designe2',
                'quantity':3
            }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
```

Now I add at list level my two dictionaries

```
all.append(list1)
all.append(liste2)
```

to replace the `[..]` in `{..}` for a single list we can do `all[0]`
But after adding the two lists and then doing `all[0]` we only have the first list whose `[..]` whose square brackets are replaced by `{..}`
I would like to have this rendering `{ {...}, {...} }`

Is this possible??

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, but still don't know what you want. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: Your `list1` and `list2` are not lusts, but dictionaries. The rendering `{ { ... }, { ... } }` makes no sense, since `{ ... }` is a dictionary (or in JavaScript an object), which is a key-value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refine what you are trying to accomplish. `lis1` is a dict, not a list. `lis1['commandes']` is a list containing a single dict, but presumably in the general case it might have more. Each of those has a key `"date"` and another key `"content"`, which is again a list of dicts ....

An arbitrary example would be to add the `commandes` from `lis2` to those in `lis1`:

```
lis1['commandes'].extend(  lis2['commandes'] )
```

which is using the list `.extend()` method to join two lists. It should yield

```
{
'code':'matata',
'commandes':[
    {
        'date':'12-10-22',
        'content':[
            {
                'article':'Article1',
                'designation':'Designe1',
                'quantity':5
            }
        ]
     },
     {
        'date':'04-08-21',
        'content':[
            {
                'article':'Article2',
                'designation':'Designe2',
                'quantity':3
            }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

"Drilling down" is just a matter of supplying array indices and dict keys as appropriate. for example,

```
lis1['commandes'][0]['content'][0]['quantity']
```

will be 5.

Added in response to comment:

Building such a structire is step-by-step. Remember that in Python, assignment is name-binding. So names referring to lists and dicts are a lot like pointers in other languages. You mutate the objects referred to in memory (if they are mutable, which lists and dicts are).

So something like:

```
lis = {}
lis['code'] = 'example'
lis['commandes'] = []
for foo in something:
    lis['commandes'] .append( build_command( foo))

...
def build_command(foo):
    command = {}
    date = datetime.date.today()
    command['date'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y')
    command['content'] = []
    for # iterating over something ...
        content = {}
        content['article'] =  
        content['designation'] =
        content['quantity'] =

        command['content'].append( content)
    return command
```

Comment: You will get None returned The .extend() method changes `lis1`, it doesn't return the changed value.  (It's not like JQuery!)

Comment: And if instead of initializing the two dictionary, I had a loop that generates the dictionaries, how to go about it??

Comment: @Pathia_Nanto see expanded answer